# Backbone + RequireJS: Collection.each() is not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I am trying to implement a simple Backbone app on top of RequireJS, but things aren't working out. Specifically, I can't make the Collection to iterate over itself. Below are my model/collection/view extracted from their respective files.

Model:

```
define([
    'backbone'
], function(Backbone) {
    'use strict';

    var m_Song = Backbone.Model.extend({
    });

    return m_Song;
});
```

Collection:

```
define([
    'backbone',
    '../models/model'
], function(Backbone, m_Song) {
    'use strict';

    var c_Songs = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: m_Song,

        url: './path/to/JSON.json',

        initialize: function() {
            this.fetch();
        }
    });

    return new c_Songs();
});
```

View:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    '../collections/collection'
], function($, _, Backbone, c_Songs) {
    'use strict';

    var v_Main = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            this.render();
        },

        render: function() {
            var $_html = (function(){
                var $_res = [];

                console.log(c_Songs);

                c_Songs.each(function($_v, $_k) {
/* =====================> Codes in here won't run <===================== */
                });

                _.each(c_Songs, function($_v, $_k) {
/* =====================> Won't run either <===================== */
                });

                return $_res;
            })();

            return this.$('tbody').append($_html);
        }
    });
```

Am I doing anything wrong? For the record, below is the output of `console.log(c_Songs);`:

```
─ d
  ├─ _byCid
  ├─ _byId
  ├─ length
  └─ models
     ├─ length
     └─ 0
        ├─ _callbacks
        ├─ _escapedAttributes
        ├─ _pending
        ├─ _previousAttributes
        ├─ _silent
        ├─ attributes
           └─ (My JSON response can be found here!)
        ├─ changed
        ├─ cid
        └─ collection
```

But I am convinced I should not access my JSON data in such a weird way like `c_Songs.models[0].attributes`; there must be something wrong.

How should I do it right to get the Collection iterate over itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [backbone.js Model.get() returns undefined, scope using coffeescript + coffee toaster?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944049/backbone-js-model-get-returns-undefined-scope-using-coffeescript-coffee-toa)

Comment: Short answer: (1) `fetch` is asynchronous, read the docs for the relevant event to wait for, (2) `console.log` is also asynchronous, don't trust it, use `console.log(x.toJSON())` or similar instead.

Comment: Thanks, pointed me to the perfect solution =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the perfect solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wookiehangover/yqpLr/) thanks to mu!